# How to find out misclassified images filenames

Tags: python

I am building a model to detect solar panel defects. I am using 255*255 images to train the model and I want to use the confusion matrix to improve my model.

The matrix gives me incorrectly classified images, but I need to find out exact filenames for the false positive and false negative images

How can I achieve this goal?

I have provided my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import keras
from keras.applications.resnet50 import  preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout
#from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout,Activation,Flatten
#from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Input
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras_applications.resnet import ResNet101
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adagrad, Adadelta, RMSprop, Adam
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import regularizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

###########################################################################################################################
## Model Initials

IMAGE_SIZE = (255, 255)


BATCH_SIZE = 24

NUM_EPOCHS = 1

WEIGHTS_FINAL = 'defectdetection.hdf5'
MODEL_FINAL = 'defectdetection.h5'
BEST_WEIGHT ='1defectdetection.hdf5'

##############################################################################################
## Loading dataset for the training process
## Define data path
# Loading the training data


img_path = 'C:/Users/TeamSoloMid/SolarCellsImages/dataset/Sample0001.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(255, 255))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
print (x.shape)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
print (x.shape)
x = preprocess_input(x)
print('Input image shape:', x.shape)

PATH = os.getcwd()


data_path = 'C:/Users/TeamSoloMid/SolarCellsImages'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)


img_data_list=[]
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(255,255))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        #print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        img_data_list.append(x)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=img_data[0]
print (img_data.shape)

#t=time.time()
# Define the number of classes
num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:1603]=0
labels[1604:3225]=1




names = ['Defect', 'Almost']

Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

#Shuffle the dataset
x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)
# Split the dataset

TestPcnt = 0.2
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                                    test_size=TestPcnt,
                                                    random_state=2)


epoch=NUM_EPOCHS

###############################################################################################
# Fine tune the resnet 101
image_input = Input(shape=(255, 255, 3))
model = ResNet101(include_top=False,
                        input_tensor=image_input,
                        weights='imagenet',  
                        backend=keras.backend,
                        layers=keras.layers,
                        models=keras.models,
                        utils=keras.utils)


# Freeze all the layers
for layer in model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

#model.summary()

last_layer = model.output
# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(last_layer)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu',name='fc-1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',name='output_layer')(x)

# this is the model we will train
net_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=out)

net_model.summary()

for layer in net_model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False

net_model.summary()

for layer in net_model.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)

#my_opti= optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00002)
#my_opti= optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001)

################################################################################################
#Define learning Rate
learning_rate = 0.00002
decay_rate = learning_rate / epoch
momentum = 0.9
sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum,
                    decay=decay_rate,
                     nesterov=False)

##############################################################################
## we will keep the weights of the epoch that scores highest in terms of accuracy on the test set.
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=BEST_WEIGHT,
                                monitor = 'val_acc',
                                verbose=1, 
                                save_best_only=True,
                                mode = 'max')
###################################################################

callback_list = [checkpointer]

net_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()
hist = net_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                     epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1,
                     callbacks = [checkpointer],
                     validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (time.time()-1))
(loss, accuracy) = net_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                      verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))
############################################################################################
## Saving The weights of the model after training
net_model.save_weights(WEIGHTS_FINAL)
print('1. Weights Saved')
net_model.save_weights(BEST_WEIGHT)
print('2. Best Weights Saved')
##############################################################################
## Saving The Complete model after training
net_model.save(MODEL_FINAL)
print('3. Model Saved')

############################################################################################
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# visualizing losses and accuracy
train_loss=hist.history['loss']
val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
train_acc=hist.history['acc']
val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
xc=range(NUM_EPOCHS)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_loss)
plt.plot(xc,val_loss)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'])
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])

plt.figure(2,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_acc)
plt.plot(xc,val_acc)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('train_acc vs val_acc')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'],loc=4)
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])

############################################################################
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import itertools
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn import svm

LABELS= ['Defect', 'Almost']

# Print confusion matrix for training data
y_pred_train = net_model.predict(X_train)


def show_confusion_matrix(validations, predictions):

    matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(validations, predictions)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    sns.heatmap(matrix,
                cmap='coolwarm',
                linecolor='white',
                linewidths=1,
                xticklabels=LABELS,
                yticklabels=LABELS,
                annot=True,
                fmt='d')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
    plt.show()

y_pred_test = net_model.predict(X_test)
# Take the class with the highest probability from the test predictions
max_y_pred_test = np.argmax(y_pred_test, axis=1)
max_y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

show_confusion_matrix(max_y_test, max_y_pred_test)

print(classification_report(max_y_test, max_y_pred_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate a checksum (i.e. md5) and use that as a dictionary key that would keep the image path as value, i.e.

```
import hashlib
...
image_paths = {}
...
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(255,255))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        #print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        img_data_list.append(x)


        # in this example i am only hashing the first 5 pixels of the image. You would probably want to use all of the pixels of the image.
        image_hash = hashlib.md5(str(x[0]) + str(x[1]) + str(x[2]) + str(x[3]) + str(x[4])).hexdigest()
        image_paths[image_hash] = img_path

        ...
```

when you want to decode the image path you simply calculate the hash again and look the path up in the dictionary

```
image_hash = hashlib.md5(str(x[0]) + str(x[1]) + str(x[2]) + str(x[3]) + str(x[4])).hexdigest()
image_path = image_paths[image_hash]
```

While that is not the most flexible approach, I believe that it will still help you achieve your goal.

One note, hashing might be pretty expensive if you have a lot of images, but if your images do not change, you only need to hash them once and save somewhere. In the consequent attempts, you would only need to load the data instead of hashing everything again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answering, I have tried your solution, and there is an IndexError like:

```
File "C:/Users/TeamSoloMid/Solar cells Defect Detection.py", line 102, in <module>
    image_hash = hashlib.md5(str(x[0])+str(x[1])+str(x[2])+str(x[3])+str(x[4])).hexdigest()

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Below is the code I added your solution in

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import keras
from keras.applications.resnet50 import  preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout
#from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout,Activation,Flatten
#from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Input
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras_applications.resnet import ResNet101
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adagrad, Adadelta, RMSprop, Adam
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import regularizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import hashlib

########################################################################################
## Model Initials

IMAGE_SIZE = (255, 255)


BATCH_SIZE = 24

NUM_EPOCHS = 1

WEIGHTS_FINAL = 'defectdetection.hdf5'
MODEL_FINAL = 'defectdetection.h5'
BEST_WEIGHT ='defectdetection.hdf5'

#########################################################################################
## Loading dataset for the training process
## Define data path
# Loading the training data


img_path = 'C:/Users/TeamSoloMid/SolarCellsImages/dataset/Sample0001.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(255, 255))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
print (x.shape)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
print (x.shape)
x = preprocess_input(x)
print('Input image shape:', x.shape)

PATH = os.getcwd()



data_path = 'C:/Users/TeamSoloMid/SolarCellsImages'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)


image_paths = {}   
img_data_list=[]
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(255,255))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        #print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        img_data_list.append(x)
image_hash = hashlib.md5(str(x[0])+str(x[1])+str(x[2])+str(x[3])+str(x[4])).hexdigest()
image_paths[image_hash] = img_path


img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=img_data[0]
print (img_data.shape)

#t=time.time()
# Define the number of classes
num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:1603]=0
labels[1604:3225]=1
#labels[3226:4847]=2




names = ['Defect', 'Almost']

# convert class labels to on-hot encoding
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

#Shuffle the dataset
x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)
# Split the dataset

TestPcnt = 0.2
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                                    test_size=TestPcnt,
                                                    random_state=2)


epoch=NUM_EPOCHS

########################################################################################
# Fine tune the resnet 101
image_input = Input(shape=(255, 255, 3))
model = ResNet101(include_top=False,
                        input_tensor=image_input,
                        weights='imagenet',  
                        backend=keras.backend,
                        layers=keras.layers,
                        models=keras.models,
                        utils=keras.utils)


# Freeze all the layers
for layer in model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

#model.summary()

last_layer = model.output
# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(last_layer)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu',name='fc-1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',name='output_layer')(x)

# this is the model we will train
net_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=out)

net_model.summary()

for layer in net_model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False

net_model.summary()

for layer in net_model.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)

#my_opti= optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00002)
#my_opti= optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001)

#########################################################################################
Define learning Rate
learning_rate = 0.00002
decay_rate = learning_rate / epoch
momentum = 0.9
sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum,
                    decay=decay_rate,
                     nesterov=False)

##############################################################################
## we will keep the weights of the epoch that scores highest in terms of accuracy on the test set.
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=BEST_WEIGHT,
                                monitor = 'val_acc',
                                verbose=1, 
                                save_best_only=True,
                                mode = 'max')
###################################################################

callback_list = [checkpointer]

net_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()
hist = net_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                     epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=1,
                     callbacks = [checkpointer],
                     validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (time.time()-1))
(loss, accuracy) = net_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                      verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))
############################################################################################
## Saving The weights of the model after training
net_model.save_weights(WEIGHTS_FINAL)
print('1. Weights Saved')
net_model.save_weights(BEST_WEIGHT)
print('2. Best Weights Saved')
##############################################################################
## Saving The Complete model after training
net_model.save(MODEL_FINAL)
print('3. Model Saved')

############################################################################################
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# visualizing losses and accuracy
train_loss=hist.history['loss']
val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
train_acc=hist.history['acc']
val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
xc=range(NUM_EPOCHS)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_loss)
plt.plot(xc,val_loss)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'])
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])

plt.figure(2,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_acc)
plt.plot(xc,val_acc)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('train_acc vs val_acc')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'],loc=4)
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])

############################################################################
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import itertools
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn import svm

LABELS= ['Defect', 'Almost']

# Print confusion matrix for training data
y_pred_train = net_model.predict(X_train)


def show_confusion_matrix(validations, predictions):

    matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(validations, predictions)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    sns.heatmap(matrix,
                cmap='coolwarm',
                linecolor='white',
                linewidths=1,
                xticklabels=LABELS,
                yticklabels=LABELS,
                annot=True,
                fmt='d')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
    plt.show()

y_pred_test = net_model.predict(X_test)
# Take the class with the highest probability from the test predictions
max_y_pred_test = np.argmax(y_pred_test, axis=1)
max_y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

show_confusion_matrix(max_y_test, max_y_pred_test)

print(classification_report(max_y_test, max_y_pred_test))

image_hash = hashlib.md5(str(x[0]) + str(x[1]) + str(x[2]) + str(x[3]) + str(x[4])).hexdigest()
image_path = image_paths[image_hash]
```